# ASMX Page: Unable to see available operations remotely

Tags: web-services, iis

I'm trying to consume a webservice and while trying to add a web reference to the .asmx page where it details the operations available, I'm getting the formatted page but no operations are listed.

However, when I'm hitting the same page locally, I can see all the operations available.

It appears that I cannot consume the webservice remotely.

Any ideas? Where would I go to configure it so that IIS will allow remote consumption?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the formatted page that .NET shows you to see the service definition? That will only show you the test page with the method definitions if you are local. From other machines it does not show that (for security reasons). However, you can still call those methods (and see them listed in the WSDL, just not the formatted test page).

Did I miss what you are asking? If that doesn't answer the question please explain more.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about. With a web reference in VS2008, I'm still unable to call the operations :(

Comment: Thanks, though, that did answer my question.